# How to visualize electron density of a specific part of the protein residue?

Tags: protein-structure, 3d-structure, structural-biology

Hi everyone (mostly who are interested in structural bioinformatics).
I face the problem that I cannot plot the electron density of a specific part of my protein. For the whole protein it is not a problem:

```
from Bio.PDB import *
import nglview as nv
import ipywidgets


pdbl = PDBList()
path = pdbl.retrieve_pdb_file('1FAT')
parser = MMCIFParser()
struct = parser.get_structure("1fat", path)
view = nv.show_biopython(struct)
view
```

But when I tried to pick up residues from 10 till 109 (`res_list = Selection.unfold_entities(struct, "R")[10:109]`) and plot I can't do that, because for `nglview` I need to have a special Object. As I'm a newbie, I'd like to address this question to specialists.

At the moment I'm trying to visualise model (structure), not electron density. But the next step is trying to find a package to visualize electron density also. I've just started becoming familiar with some open packages.

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Hi @KitsuneBreeze its a good question and looks to be resolved. Please remember to "accept" and "upvote"

Answer (score 2):

NGLview runs off the JavaScript libray NGL, which is documented as a series of very helpful examples: [in the gallery](http://nglviewer.org/ngl/gallery/). The commands are not one-to-one (slightly frustratingly), but it is helpful as you can figure it out easily with a few `dir` and `help` commands. In this case whatever example of density being loaded it will reveals that it's a different component —this is the same everywhere as density files do not contain atomic coordinates. Unfortunately, there's not a direct way to generate a new `ComponentViewer` from different sources to an `NGLWidget` and you cannot merge two of them: the various `.show_*` functions return an `NGLWidget` but aren't part of it.

First, I am not sure why you are going through a convoluted route for loading a PDB code:

```
pdb_code = '1fat'

import nglview as nv

view: nv.NGLWidget = nv.show_pdbid(pdb_code)
```

Now, on loading the component a representation is added to it.
These can hide the representation you then add and things will not make sense, until this detail is recalled! I fall in that pit nearly every time.
But we can change it with update command:

```
# I don't like wonky sheets
view.update_cartoon(smoothSheets=True, color='salmon', component=0)
```

Now let's add the density map the circuitous way (no `.show_url`).

```
import requests, io
response: requests.Response = requests.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/coordinates/files/1fat.ccp4')
response.raise_for_status()
fh = io.BytesIO(response.content)
comp: nv.component.ComponentViewer = view.add_component(fh, ext='ccp4')
```

Now we can add a surface representation, but first let's clear the default.
For the arguments I had a gander at the example:

```
view.clear_representations(component=1)
view.add_representation('surface', 
                        color='grey', 
                        wireframe=True, 
                        isolevel=1.5,
                        component=1)
view.center('100-110:A')
view
```